# Do you have to use a weapon for it to get affinity?

Tags: warframe

Information that will give relevance to answers and the question being asked: I am referencing Warframe, and my rank is just below rank 5 at the point I am posting this question.  I have a few maxed out weapons in each category: main, secondary, melee. I also have a couple max rank frames as well.  I haven't played in a long time, and have recently picked the game back up, so I am barely at/past Earth. I also play solo only, due to family, don't have the ability to commit to a game/mission.

So I have a lot of really weak weapons that I want to max out and sell, but I really don't want to spend hours grinding low level missions to do so.  If I carry a maxed out weapon and use that, would the low rank weapon still get affinity?  Or do I have to actually use the weapon for it to get affinity?

Comment: I'll say this, Defense missions with a group are the best way to level weapons.  As long as you're in range, you get 1/4 of the affinity for other players kills across all of your items; Defense maps are small enough that you're almost always in the range of all other players.  On PC Helene, Saturn and Hydron, Sedna are the most popular missions for leveling things.  Helene because Orokin Cells drop there, Hydron because it's the highest level Defense mission in the game.

Comment: Must not have read the second half of the first paragraph, I can't commit to missions, may need to abandon at drop of hat, so can't group either.  Also, just got most of earth cleared, think I've got one mission into phobos, so most of the missions you are even referencing I don't have access to

Comment: There isn't much to commit to on Hydron, most groups of randos will stay for 10 rounds, then extract.  It's 10 minutes or so for better results than you would get solo.  Also depending on the group and other factors, simply going AFK for a few usually won't bother anyone as usually someone is carrying (heavily).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Affinity will be granted to anything equipped [not necessarily in use] for

- Challenge tasks
- Terminal hacks
- Mission objectives
- Collecting affinity orbs
- Performing codex Scans
- Being in proximity to kills by allies in multiplayer

Objective based missions and challenge tasks will probably be your main source of affinity without actually using the weapons.

Comment: Do you get affinity for killing enemies? And if so, if the weapon being used is max rank, would that affinity be split amongst the rest of your weapons and frame?  That is the core to my question, because I'm on missions that are like level 12+, but I'm trying to level weapons like the Furis, Strum, and Bronco: really early weapons

Comment: Affinity for kills is split between the frame and the weapon used to make the kill, it will not be split to weapons and equipment not used for the kill even if it is max ranked.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, means I'm going to be grinding a while on the low level missions T_T

Comment: Get a taxi to Hydron on Sedna and play for 10 rounds, if you have an affinity booster and only the warframe + the weapon you want to level equipped, the weapon is ranked to max in those 10 rounds. It even counts affinity after maxing it so it might be possible to rank 2 weapons but I don't think they'll be maxed then.